Number of connection in flink is per job or per task?
When using the DataStax Cassandra driver with a Cassandra Sink Builder in Flink, is the connection pool created per task or per application? If I have a parallelism of 14, does the core.connections setting apply to each task individually or to the entire application? For example, if I set core.connections to 1, will I end up with 14 connections to Cassandra (one per task), or just one shared connection across the application?
